# AWS IoT: ForbiddenException: Forbidden

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I'm expieriencing an error, while trying the `getThingShadow()` method.

No Node.js, just plain Javascript.

The related Code:

```
var params = {
  thingName: 'test123'
};
var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
  secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
  sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
  region: AWSConfiguration.region, 
  endpoint: AWSConfiguration.host
});

iotdata.getThingShadow(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack); 
  } 
  else {
    console.log(data);         
  }
});
```

The error Message:

> GET  https://XXX.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/things/test123/shadow
>
> [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 106ms] ForbiddenException: Forbidden
>
> Stack-Trace: //many many lines of unrelevant text

My IAM Rules:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Connect",
        "iot:Receive",
        "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
        "iot:GetThingShadow"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You may see, i allowed literally EVERYTHING, still i'm getting the Forbidden exception, why?
BTW: The User Authentication (AWS-Cognito) is successful, i'm receiving all needed credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by attaching the cognitoID to policy via IoT web-console (manually) and it works.

Comment: What do you mean by this?